# R assign the output from auto.arima function to a variable

Tags: r, time-series, arima

I'm analyzing time series data which is based on a data frame that has dates, products, and price. In the data frame, it gives price of each product for each date. I am trying to forecast the price of each product using ARIMA.

I've made multiple sub-dataframes for each product and ran `auto.arima()` to find the AR and MA of the time series data of each product. I found out that each product has different AR and MA.

What I'm trying to do is making a loop that runs for the number of products and forecast the price of each product a week ahead. Since each product data has different outputs from `auto.arima()`, I need a function that assigns the output from `auto.arima()` to three variables (one for AR, one for MA, and one for difference order). How can I do this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

```
a <- auto.arima(mtcars$qsec)
```

Use `forecast::arimaorder(a)` to extract AR, I, MA terms.

```
# p d q 
# 0 1 1
```